# Find feature classes that are not in one database and copy them to another

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3

I have a database that meets a particular data standard and another that only partially meets this same standard. I am trying to combine data from the partially standardized database to the standardized database without creating repeats.

Using the Python sets module seems like it may provide a solution. The code below only provides me with an empty list or a list that doesn't contain the intended feature classes. Once I get this code to work, my intention is to use the produced list to insert into something similar to `arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion (migrate, r'C:\database2.gdb', filename)`

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env

# List data that is in DB1 (partially compliant DB)
workspace = r'C:\database1.gdb'
FCs_in_DB1 = []
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in arcpy.da.Walk(workspace,
                                                  datatype="FeatureClass",
                                                  type="Any"):
    for filename in filenames:
        FCs_in_DB1.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))

# List data that is in DB2 (compliant DB)
workspace = r'C:\database2.gdb'
FCs_in_DB2 = []
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in arcpy.da.Walk(workspace,
                                                  datatype="FeatureClass",
                                                  type="Any"):
    for filename in filenames:
        FCs_in_DB2.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))

# What I have tried so far. 
# I have also switched the 1 and 2 in list names in attempt to get desired results.
#migrate = list(set(FCs_in_DB2) - set(FCs_in_DB1))
#migrate = [x for x in FCs_in_DB2 if x not in FCs_in_DB1]
#migrate = FCs_in_DB1.symmetric_difference(FCs_in_DB2))
#migrate = list(set(FCs_in_DB1) ^ set(FCs_in_DB2))

print migrate
```

I am hoping to find what is wrong with my code or perhaps be led to a better approach to this problem altogether?

Comment: Can you please confirm these are File Geodatabases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[List Feature Classes](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/listfeatureclasses.htm) produces a list, so create a list of the feature classes in both databases, then test if the feature classes in the non-standardized db exist in the standardized one, and copy them over if they don't exist.

```
db1 = r'C:\database1.gdb' # Standardized database to copy to
db2 = r'C:\database2.gdb' # Non-Standardized db to copy from

arcpy.env.workspace = db1
db1FCs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses() # get list of standardized db feature classes

arcpy.env.workspace = db2
db2FCs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses() # get list of non-standardized db feature classes

for fc in db2FCs:
    # If the feature class in non-standardized db doesn't 
    # exist in the standardized db, then copy it over
    if fc not in db1FCs: 
        arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(fc, db1, fc)
```

**Note:** I have reversed your two databases, so you may need to switch `database1` for `database2`